# How to find if two objects have been close for a certain amount of time

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I'm new with ksqlDB and trying to get my head around the difference between the different types of windowing. Currently I'm trying to populate a table for the following:

If two objects have been closer than 1 km, having a speed of less than 2, for longer than one hour.

I have two streams, `vessels` and `reefers`. Both these streams are continuously updated with new positional data.

Currently my query looks like this:

```
SELECT VESSELS.ID, LATEST_BY_OFFSET(VESSELS.NAME)
  FROM vessels
  INNER JOIN REEFERS
  WITHIN 3 HOURS
  ON reefers.id_2 = vessels.id_2
  WINDOW HOPPING (size 1 HOURS, advance by 15 MINUTES)
  WHERE GEO_DISTANCE(reefers.LAT, reefers.LON, vessels.LAT, vessels.LON, 'KM') < 1 AND vessels.speed < 2.0 AND vessels.id != reefer.id
  GROUP BY VESSELS.ID
```

Source data for `vessels`:

```
|ID           |NAME        |LAT      |LON       |SPEED  |ID_2   |
|257184340    |KRYSSHOLM   |70.6807  |21.6932   |0.8    |1      |
```

The `reefers` stream has the same structure

As the final result I'm only interested in a list with vessels that fulfils the criteria. As of now this query gives me a long list with every datapoint (positional update).

Regards
Lars

Comment: Are you able to share a sample of the source events?

Comment: Are you able to share in your question  the output of `PRINT <topic> FROM BEGINNING LIMIT 10;` or something like that? It will make it easier to try and mock up the query and figure out if it's possible or not.

Comment: Added now, @RobinMoffatt . Does that help?

Comment: What's `id_2`? This looks like the field on which you're joining the streams, but how is it populated/derived?

Comment: That is a dummy field that I have added so that I am able to use the GEO_DISTANCE function to calculate the distance between two types of vessels. It is not pretty and not very efficient, but it does the job.

To give a bit more context. I'm doing a research project to see can if I can detect if two vessels have been close to each other for a certain amount of time. This is an indicator for transshipment and is something that I'm looking into. Thanks for your rapid replies so far, @RobinMoffatt!

Comment: that makes sense, thanks. I think I have a solution. is the source of data you're using public? It would be useful to test it out. You can reach me @rmoff on https://launchpass.com/confluentcommunity if it's easier.

Comment: The data source I'm using is public, but you need to processes it a bit before it's useful. It is a "raw" AIS stream that is accessible on IP 153.44.253.27 port 5631. 

To my knowledge, it looks like the WHERE clause in the query does it's job, but I'm not getting my head around how to only retrieve the vessels that has been closer than 1 km for more than two hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
-- Source streams & topics
CREATE OR REPLACE STREAM reefers_v00 (ID BIGINT, NAME VARCHAR, LAT DOUBLE, LON DOUBLE, SPEED double, DUMMY INT) WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='reefers_v00',partitions=4,replicas=1,value_format='protobuf');
CREATE OR REPLACE STREAM vessels_v00 (ID BIGINT, NAME VARCHAR, LAT DOUBLE, LON DOUBLE, SPEED double, DUMMY INT) WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='vessels_v00',partitions=4,replicas=1,value_format='protobuf');
```

```sql
-- Test data
INSERT INTO vessels_v00 (ROWTIME, ID, NAME, LAT, LON,SPEED,DUMMY) VALUES (STRINGTOTIMESTAMP('2021-01-29 12:03:04', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss', 'Europe/London'),28,'TEST1',-56.72016, 83.43720, 0.8,1);
INSERT INTO reefers_v00 (ROWTIME, ID, NAME, LAT, LON,SPEED,DUMMY) VALUES (STRINGTOTIMESTAMP('2021-01-29 12:03:04', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss', 'Europe/London'),21,'TEST2',-56.72016, 83.44720, 1.8,1);
INSERT INTO vessels_v00 (ROWTIME, ID, NAME, LAT, LON,SPEED,DUMMY) VALUES (STRINGTOTIMESTAMP('2021-01-29 12:33:04', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss', 'Europe/London'),28,'TEST1',-56.72016, 83.43720, 0.8,1);
INSERT INTO reefers_v00 (ROWTIME, ID, NAME, LAT, LON,SPEED,DUMMY) VALUES (STRINGTOTIMESTAMP('2021-01-29 12:33:04', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss', 'Europe/London'),21,'TEST2',-56.72016, 83.44720, 1.8,1);
INSERT INTO vessels_v00 (ROWTIME, ID, NAME, LAT, LON,SPEED,DUMMY) VALUES (STRINGTOTIMESTAMP('2021-01-29 13:01:04', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss', 'Europe/London'),28,'TEST1',-56.72016, 83.43720, 0.8,1);
INSERT INTO reefers_v00 (ROWTIME, ID, NAME, LAT, LON,SPEED,DUMMY) VALUES (STRINGTOTIMESTAMP('2021-01-29 13:01:04', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss', 'Europe/London'),21,'TEST2',-56.72016, 83.44720, 1.8,1);

INSERT INTO vessels_v00 (ROWTIME, ID, NAME, LAT, LON,SPEED,DUMMY) VALUES (STRINGTOTIMESTAMP('2021-01-28 12:03:04', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss', 'Europe/London'),9,'wibble',-56.72016, 83.43720, 0.8,1);
INSERT INTO reefers_v00 (ROWTIME, ID, NAME, LAT, LON,SPEED,DUMMY) VALUES (STRINGTOTIMESTAMP('2021-01-28 13:03:05', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss', 'Europe/London'),11,'foo',-56.62016, 83.43720, 0.8,1);
INSERT INTO vessels_v00 (ROWTIME, ID, NAME, LAT, LON,SPEED,DUMMY) VALUES (STRINGTOTIMESTAMP('2021-01-28 13:04:04', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss', 'Europe/London'),9,'wibble',-56.61016, 83.45720, 0.8,1);
INSERT INTO vessels_v00 (ROWTIME, ID, NAME, LAT, LON,SPEED,DUMMY) VALUES (STRINGTOTIMESTAMP('2021-01-28 14:02:03', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss', 'Europe/London'),9,'wibble',-56.61016, 83.45720, 0.8,1);
INSERT INTO reefers_v00 (ROWTIME, ID, NAME, LAT, LON,SPEED,DUMMY) VALUES (STRINGTOTIMESTAMP('2021-01-28 14:02:04', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss', 'Europe/London'),11,'foo',-56.62016, 83.43720, 0.8,1);
INSERT INTO reefers_v00 (ROWTIME, ID, NAME, LAT, LON,SPEED,DUMMY) VALUES (STRINGTOTIMESTAMP('2021-01-28 14:05:04', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss', 'Europe/London'),11,'foo',-56.62016, 83.44720, 0.8,1);
INSERT INTO vessels_v00 (ROWTIME, ID, NAME, LAT, LON,SPEED,DUMMY) VALUES (STRINGTOTIMESTAMP('2021-01-28 14:05:10', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss', 'Europe/London'),9,'wibble',-56.64016, 83.44720, 0.8,1);
INSERT INTO vessels_v00 (ROWTIME, ID, NAME, LAT, LON,SPEED,DUMMY) VALUES (STRINGTOTIMESTAMP('2021-01-28 14:09:04', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss', 'Europe/London'),9,'wibble',-57.64016, 83.44720, 0.8,1);
INSERT INTO reefers_v00 (ROWTIME, ID, NAME, LAT, LON,SPEED,DUMMY) VALUES (STRINGTOTIMESTAMP('2021-01-28 14:10:00', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss', 'Europe/London'),11,'foo',-56.62016, 83.44720, 0.8,1);
INSERT INTO reefers_v00 (ROWTIME, ID, NAME, LAT, LON,SPEED,DUMMY) VALUES (STRINGTOTIMESTAMP('2021-01-28 15:15:04', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss', 'Europe/London'),11,'foo',-56.62016, 83.45720, 0.8,1);
INSERT INTO reefers_v00 (ROWTIME, ID, NAME, LAT, LON,SPEED,DUMMY) VALUES (STRINGTOTIMESTAMP('2021-01-28 19:03:04', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss', 'Europe/London'),22,'bar',-56.68016, 83.44720, 0.8,1);
```

```sql
-- Join the streams
-- Assumes that movement reports within a minute of each other can be counted as the same timestamp
-- Creates a new field to indicate if the two objects are within the criteria (range & speed)
SET 'auto.offset.reset' = 'earliest';

CREATE STREAM MOVEMENTS_v00 AS
SELECT TIMESTAMPTOSTRING(v.ROWTIME, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss', 'Europe/London') AS TS_v,
  v.*,
  TIMESTAMPTOSTRING(r.ROWTIME, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss', 'Europe/London') AS TS_r,
  r.*,
  geo_distance(v.lat, v.lon, r.lat, r.lon, 'KM') as distance,
  case
    when geo_distance(v.lat, v.lon, r.lat, r.lon, 'KM') < 3 
     and (r.speed <2 and v.speed < 2) then 1
    else 0
  end as in_range_and_speed
FROM vessels_v00 v
  inner join reefers_v00 r 
  WITHIN 1 minute on R.DUMMY = V.DUMMY
  ;
```

```sql
-- Query the data for debug purposes
SELECT TIMESTAMPTOSTRING(ROWTIME,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss','Europe/London') AS TS, V_ID, R_ID, V_SPEED, R_SPEED, DISTANCE, IN_RANGE_AND_SPEED 
  FROM MOVEMENTS_v00 
  EMIT CHANGES;
```

```sql
-- Select object pairs using a session window based on the critera flag
-- and a predicate on the duration of the session
SELECT V_ID,
  V_NAME,
  R_ID,
  R_NAME,
  MIN(DISTANCE) AS CLOSEST_DISTANCE_KM,
  MAX(DISTANCE) AS FURTHEST_DISTANCE_KM,
  COLLECT_LIST(DISTANCE) AS DISTANCE_POINTS_KM,
  TIMESTAMPTOSTRING( MIN(ROWTIME), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss', 'Europe/London' ) AS FIRST_TS,
  TIMESTAMPTOSTRING( MAX(ROWTIME), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss', 'Europe/London' ) AS LAST_TS,
  (MAX(ROWTIME) - MIN(ROWTIME)) / 1000 AS DIFF_SEC
FROM MOVEMENTS_v00 WINDOW SESSION (1 HOUR)
where IN_RANGE_AND_SPEED = 1
GROUP BY V_ID,
  V_NAME,
  R_ID,
  R_NAME,
  IN_RANGE_AND_SPEED 
HAVING (MAX(ROWTIME) - MIN(ROWTIME)) / 1000 > 3600  
  EMIT CHANGES;
```